# Left-handed vs. Right-handed User

Tags: usability, interaction-design, usability-study, swipe

How to manage some special interactions like swipe from left to right at bottom of screen or vice versa, as it would be easy for a right-handed person when compared to left-handed person?

For example, Google Dialer had a right-swipe earlier to pick the call.

[image]

Even iOS has button at right to pick:

[image]

Me being a right-handed person, I always operate my phone with my left hand. Is there any study indicating the percentage of left-Handed phone Users?

If any case of special problem comes as I mentioned,

1. Should we ignore them?
2. Or should we change the whole interaction basing that?

Google has changed how they handle this:

[image]

Comment: Below given discussion could be helpful https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/107729/arranging-menu-or-buttons-in-mobile-apps

Answer (score 1):

Design according to thumb coverage:

http://blog.usabilla.com/designing-thumbs-thumb-zone/

http://thumbzone.co/

Comment: Stop using that diagram. The original author said that the thumb diagram isn't accurate because not all people hold their phone with just one hand: http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2017/03/design-for-fingers-touch-and-people-part-1.php

Comment: Instead: trust what your users are doing, not what some diagram tells you to do.